# tsung not sending or receiving any data

Tags: load-testing, tsung

i have an api which i was load testing with tsung.All was ok. Now , i am getting no result using varibles data from file in load testing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tsung SYSTEM "/usr/local/Cellar/tsung/1.7.0/share/tsung/tsung-1.0.dtd">
<tsung loglevel="warning">

  <clients>
    <client host="localhost" use_controller_vm="true"/>
  </clients>

  <servers>
    <server host="127.0.0.1" port="8030" type="tcp"/>
  </servers>

  <load>
    <arrivalphase phase="1" duration="1" unit="minute">
      <users arrivalrate="100" unit="second"/>
    </arrivalphase>
  </load>
  <options>
    <option name="file_server" id="ids" value="id.csv" ></option>
  </options>
  <sessions>
    <session name="dummy" weight="1" type="ts_http">
        <setdynvars sourcetype="file" fileid="ids" order="iter">
            <var name="uid" />
        </setdynvars>
        <request subst="true">
            <http url="/api/v1/locations?user_ids=%%_uid" method="GET"  version="1.1" >
                <http_header name="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>
                <http_header name="RLS-Referrer" value="vivasoftltd.com"/>
            </http>
        </request>
    </session>
  </sessions>
</tsung>
```

this config file.
and the id.csv is

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

now generating report showing

```
size_rcv is equal to 0 !
size_sent is equal to 0 !
```

And the report.html is showing all empty and all errors.
How can i solve this

Answer (score 0):

Your dynamic variable substitution is incorrect inside your request.

`<http url="/api/v1/locations?user_ids=***%%_uid%%***" method="GET"  version="1.1" >`

Please check this [link](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/conf-advanced-features.html#dynamic-variables) for Tsung documentation regarding *Dynamic variables*.